# Changing columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[Image containing the problem, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSmDT.png)

Please review the image

Comment: ```df.melt(id_vars='Campus',var_name='Month',value_name='Value')``` Please have a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post your next question :)

Comment: Instead of the image, please copy and paste the text. In this way it  will be easier for the others to reuse the text for testing.

Comment: [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631466/17850902) solves your problem and explains the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the function [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), which to massage a DataFrame into a format where one or more columns are identifier variables (here `Campus`), while all other columns, considered measured variables (here `Apr`, `May,` June`), are "unpivoted" to the row axis as the following code snippet illustrates:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Campus':  ['A', 'B'],
        'Apr': [55, 1],
        'May': [56, 2],
        'June': [57, 3],
        })

df2 = df1.melt(id_vars='Campus',var_name='Month',value_name='Value')
```

`df2` has then the following content:

```
    Campus  Month   Value
0   A       Apr     55
1   B       Apr     1
2   A       May     56
3   B       May     2
4   A       June    57
5   B       June    3
```